# On simple closed-forms involving the Euler's totient function and the Digamma function

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, proof-verification, totient-function, digamma-function

In the **Wikipedia** article for the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) one finds some identities due to **Gauss.** I've used the fourth of those from the section **Some finite sums involving the digamma function** to show if there were no mistakes that for $m>1$

$$\sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq m-1 \\ (k,m)=1}}\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}\psi\left(\frac{r}{m}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi r k}{m}\right)=\pi\frac{m\phi(m)}{2}-\pi\frac{m\phi(m)}{2}=0,$$

where $\phi(m)$ is the **Euler's totient** function and as you see in the reference $\psi(s)$ is the **digamma function**.

My approach was use Apostol's Exercise 14 with $f(x)=x$, from Chapter 2 of **Apostol**, Introduction to Analytic Number Theory, **Springer** (1976), also I need that $\sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq m-1 \\ (k,n)=1}}k=\frac{n}{2}\phi(n)+\frac{n}{2}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)=\frac{n}{2}\phi(n)+\frac{n}{2}$, on assumption that $n>1$. Also the **Gauss** identity for the sum of the first $n$ positive integers.

> **Question 1.** Can you say if my statement (the first identity of current post) was right? **Thanks.**

After I tried the same with the other identity that is feasible do this calculations, that is the third, also due to Gauss. My calculations were $$\sum_{\substack{1\leq k\leq m-1 \\ (k,m)=1}}\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}\psi\left(\frac{r}{m}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi r k}{m}\right)=m\phi(m)\log 2+m\cdot\log\left(\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq m-1 \\ (k,m)=1}}\sin \frac{k\pi}{m}\right)+\gamma\phi(m).$$

**There was a typo, fixed.**

> **Question.** Is there a *nice* closed-form for the factor $$\prod_{\substack{1\leq k\leq m-1 \\ (k,m)=1}}\sin \frac{k\pi}{m}$$ in the context of this post (I say nice/good in the context of the first question)? **Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the first question the answer is yes. Note that $$\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle \left(k,m\right)=1}}{1\leq k\leq m}}k=\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle \left(k,m\right)=1}}{1\leq k\leq m-1}}k=\frac{m\phi\left(m\right)}{2}\tag{1}$$ so $$\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle \left(k,m\right)=1}}{1\leq k\leq m-1}}\sum_{r\leq m-1}\psi\left(\frac{r}{m}\right)\cos\left(\frac{2\pi rk}{m}\right)=\pi\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle \left(k,m\right)=1}}{1\leq k\leq m-1}}k-\frac{\pi m}{2}\sum_{\underset{{\scriptstyle \left(k,m\right)=1}}{1\leq k\leq m-1}}1=\color{red}{0}.$$ About the second question we have that (we will indicate the condition $\left(k,m\right)=1
 $ with the symbol $'$)$$\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{m}\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\frac{e^{i\pi k/m}-e^{-i\pi k/m}}{2i}
 $$ $$=\left(2i\right)^{-\phi\left(m\right)}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'e^{-i\pi k/m}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\left(e^{2i\pi k/m}-1\right)
 $$ $$=\left(2i\right)^{-\phi\left(m\right)}e^{-i\pi\phi\left(m\right)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\left(e^{2i\pi k/m}-1\right)
 $$ $$=\left(-2i\right)^{-\phi\left(m\right)}e^{-i\pi\phi\left(m\right)/2}\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\left(1-\zeta_{m}^{k}\right)
 $$ where in the second last identity we used again $(1)$ and in the last identity we wrote $$e^{2i\pi k/m}=\zeta_{m}^{k}
 $$ i.e. the usual way to indicate the $n-$th roots of unity and we changed sign. So we have done, since the last product has already been studied by Steven Galovich (see [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/1988/0025570x.di021149.02p0095y.pdf)) and $$\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\left(1-\zeta_{m}^{k}\right)=e^{\Lambda\left(m\right)}=\begin{cases}
p, & m=p^{n}\textrm{ for some }n\geq1\\
1, & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ where $\Lambda\left(m\right)
 $ is the Von Mangoldt function. It remains to note that $$ \left(-2i\right)^{-\phi\left(m\right)}=2^{-\phi\left(m\right)}\left(-1\right)^{3\phi\left(m\right)/2}
 $$ and $$\exp\left(\frac{-i\pi\phi\left(m\right)}{2}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{\pi\phi\left(m\right)}{2}\right)
 $$ since $\phi\left(n\right)
 $ is even. So finally

> $$\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}'\sin\left(\frac{\pi k}{m}\right)=\color{red}{2^{-\phi\left(m\right)}e^{\Lambda\left(m\right)}}$$

since $$\left(-1\right)^{3\phi\left(m\right)/2}\cos\left(\frac{\pi\phi\left(m\right)}{2}\right)=1.$$ Note that you can also write $$e^{\Lambda\left(m\right)}=\frac{\textrm{lcm}\left(1,\dots,m\right)}{\mbox{lcm}\left(1,\dots,m-1\right)}.$$

Comment: Curiously I tried also today get simple closed-forms from products involving cyclotomic polynomials and nth roots of the unity. Is very nice, you are very valuable as mathematician. Very thanks much for this new lesson.